# jQuery ajax load only text of a certain element

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to `$.load()` some data from other page (`foo.html`). Say I want my current `<title>Current</title>` to be the same as foo's title, `<title>Foo</title>`.
What I'm doing is:
`$("title").load("foo.html title");`

The problem is I get foo's title with the `<title>` tag:
`<title><title>Foo</title></title>`
and it obviously doesn't work.
How can I get only the text of foo's title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feels like a hack but it works.

```
$("<div>").load("foo.html title", function(){
  $('title').text($(this).text());
});
```

Even though this is a hack, I made a tiny plugin you can use.

```
$.fn.loadText = function(path, selector){
  var node = this[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();
  $("<div>").load(path + " " + selector, function(){
    $(node).text($(this).text());
  });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$('title').loadText("some path", 'title');
```

If you wanted to load into the `title`, the text of another tag...

```
$('title').loadText("some path", 'div#foo');
```

Comment: `$.get` doesn't wok that way, you cannot load just the title tag of the page. Also you are replacing all title tags in the page with the `data`.

Comment: I was thinking of something like that but not in such a short code like this. It worked, thanks. :)

Comment: @SPL_Splinter you're welcome. I made an edit if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

I would use global `$.get(url, data, success)` instead as suggested on the jquery. This works (tested):

```
$.get('foo.html', function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    $('title').text($(XMLHttpRequest.responseXML).find('title').text());  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like it's gonna work but the code would mess my head a little. I'm gonna take Kyle's answer. Thanks, anyway. :)

Answer (score -2):

try this...

```
$("title").load("foo.html").find("title").text()
```

Comment: I think the $.load() method doesn't work like this. This loads all the content of foo.html and puts it inside <title>. Then it searches for <title> inside of it and takes the text of it. Then it does nothing with this text. The final product of this line would be a string, and we know a code line with a simple string in it does nothing.